# In Gamemaker Studio 2 how can I find out in code whether the platform is HTML5 or not?

Tags: game-maker

I want to be able to run or not run code depending on which platform I am building for. Some code should only run for the HTML5 platform. How can I find out whether the platform being run is HTML5 inside my gamemaker events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check what browser the game is currently being run in with the [`os_browser`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/operating%20system/os_browser.html) constant. If the game is not being run in a browser the constant will be `browser_not_a_browser`. So to check if it is being run in a browser simply do:

```
if os_browser != browser_not_a_browser {
     // Being run in a browser
}
```